# Did a pre-schism Roman Bishop say he is not special?

Tags: church-history, papacy, reference-request

I heard recently that one of the pre-schism Bishops of Rome went out of his way to say that the Bishop of Rome does not possess any special authority, power, etc over any other bishop and is merely the "first among equals". Is that true and, if so, can anyone find the quote and its attribution? Google is failing me.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in this question:

[What exactly did Pope Gregory the Great mean by “Universal Bishop?”](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26760/what-exactly-did-pope-gregory-the-great-mean-by-universal-bishop)

Pope St. Gregory the Great, 6th century, from his epistles.